# EXCEL VBA - Define Sub or Function

Tags: vba, excel

How can I define a sub or function in VBA?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Send_Mail
End Sub
```

In Worksheet "Sheet1" I have a `CommandButton` called **Send_Mail** and in "Sheet2" I have also a `CommandButton`. When I click the `CommandButton` in Sheet2 I want that the Button in Sheet1 will run.

With my code the : error "Sub or Function is not defined" appears.

**EDIT:**

Code for Send_Mail:

```
Public Sub Send_Mail_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim nameList As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error GoTo cleanup

    For i = 4 To 22                                                                         
        If Range("B4").Value <> "" Then                                                        
            nameList = nameList & ";" & Range("C" & i).Value
        End If
    Next
        With OutMail
            .To = nameList
            .Subject = "Subject Line"
            .Body = "Body Text"
            .Send
        End With
cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "E-Mail sent."
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to make sure `Sub Send_Mail` is located in a regular code module, and not a worksheet module, that way it is accessible

Comment: Can you please show more of your codes? And what do you mean with this one: `When I click the CommandButton in Sheet2 I want that the Button in Sheet1 will run`, you mean the function assigned to button 1?

Comment: I went to "Create Macro" paste the code from Send_Mail to it. Saved it as Send_Mail .. but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the underlying sub procedure attached to the Sheet1 button has been named but it is likely it has a similar name.

```
'Sheet2's button sub procedure
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Or `Sheet1.Send_Mail`?